# SonarQube 6.2 Compute Engine NullPointerException

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I have a single project on my SonarQube server that has started failing in the past few days (probably due to using the Upgrade Center to upgrade a few plugins and/or playing with the Python profile?).  I have turned off the Python profile and restarted the server but the ce.log file contains the following when this project scan is uploaded to the server (other projects still work fine):

```
2017.12.06 10:24:02 INFO  ce[AWAtEf8ZpSfG1LhTt-eQ][o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Execute task | project=mypackage:myproject | type=REPORT | id=AWAtEf8ZpSfG1LhTt-eQ
2017.12.06 10:24:04 ERROR ce[AWAtEf8ZpSfG1LhTt-eQ][o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AWAtEf8ZpSfG1LhTt-eQ
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:210)
        at com.google.common.base.Splitter.splitToList(Splitter.java:416)
        at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.filemove.FileMoveDetectionStep.getFile(FileMoveDetectionStep.java:239)
        at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.filemove.FileMoveDetectionStep.computeScoreMatrix(FileMoveDetectionStep.java:208)
        at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.filemove.FileMoveDetectionStep.execute(FileMoveDetectionStep.java:127)
        at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:64)
        at org.sonar.server.computation.task.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:52)
        at org.sonar.server.computation.task.projectanalysis.taskprocessor.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:75)
        at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:84)
        at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:57)
        at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017.12.06 10:24:04 ERROR ce[AWAtEf8ZpSfG1LhTt-eQ][o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=oracle.weblogic.lifecycle:wls-deploy | type=REPORT | id=AWAtEf8ZpSfG1LhTt-eQ | time=1423ms
```

Any clues?

Comment: My first guess would be : could you try using the latest LTS 6.7 ?

Answer (score 1):

This bug is fixed in version 6.3 (see https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8835 and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/MKlBDdMZJRk).

Please note that it's highly recommended to use the Long-Term Support version, which is 6.7 at the time of writing. It prevents from facing annoying bugs like the one you face.